# Is this an error in launching the AVD? Android Studio emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 128MB

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, haxm

This is my first time (after n amount of years) to go back in Android development. It's my first time to use Android Studio and tried out the Android Virtual Device. I'm a total noob at this, so why not ask the ever helpful Stack Overflow community!

In my first try in launching the virtual device, a black screen with "Android" is just there and I'd click the buttons found at the side of the virtual device like Power, Volume Up, nothing happens. I checked the error in Android Studio:

```
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 96MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 256MB
```

I checked the Intel HAXM Setting and it was set to the Default Size of 1024 MB which is bigger than 96MB. I deleted the Virtual Device and created a new one and it ran smoothly (there was the usual home screen). I checked the console in Android Studio and got this back

```
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 128MB
ERROR: resizing partition failed with exit code 1
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
Creating filesystem with parameters:
Warning: requested ram_size 1536M too big, reduced to 1024M
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
```

Can anyone explain the Error? And why is there the same warning from the emulator saying that it's set below 128MB when the setting is more than that. It's good to know that "`HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode`" that's good and all but I also want to know if the setting is efficient enough that it won't slow my computer's performance, speed and memory? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i faced the same problem but resolved by changing in build.gradle

```
 buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
```

to

```
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```