# Ionic run android is not building apk

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I shifted development of my ionic app from windows to ubuntu 14.04 now. I installed everything new. "Ionic build android" command is working but when i run "ionic run android" or "ionic emulate android" it only starts emulator no BUILD SUCCESS and LAUNCH SUCCESS is shown in console. Also app does not get installed in emulator.

```
ajeet@samsung:~/deployments/mobile_app/chmapp$ ionic run android
Native thread-sleep not available.
This will result in much slower performance, but it will still work.
You should re-install spawn-sync or upgrade to the lastest version of node if possible.
Check /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/cross-spawn/node_modules/spawn-sync/error.log for more details
Running command: /home/ajeet/deployments/mobile_app/chmapp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/ajeet/deployments/mobile_app/chmapp
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
No target specified, deploying to emulator
No emulator specified, defaulting to Nexus
Waiting for emulator...
sh: 1: glxinfo: not found
sh: 1: glxinfo: not found
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 256MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 512MB
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
```

Comment: first start the emulator and then run. launching emulator at run-time often leads to a timeout

Comment: Thanks , if i run "ionic emulate android" first and then "ionic run android" then its working

Comment: great, also posting this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments.

Keep the emulator running first and then execute. Invoking the emulator at runtime often leads to timeout.

Comment: One more question , i just tried ionic tabs sample. Built apk is working in real android device but now in emulator its show "Unfortunately, app_name has stopped". When does it happen ?

Comment: No error in the console. Only warning while starting emulator
`emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 256MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 512MB`. When i run ionic run command,  app just starts and close with  "Unfortunately, app_name has stopped" alert while its working on real android device.

Comment: that's a different issue but see if this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113166/is-this-an-error-in-launching-the-avd-android-studio-emulator-warning-vm-heap?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Run this command, it will show the missing things
npm list
would shows you need "try-thread-sleep" to use spawn-sync.
So, add bellow in your "package.json" and "npm install" again.
"try-thread-sleep": "^1.0.0".
Hope it will help. copied.

Answer (score -1):

you need to install emulator in Ubuntu then only you can able to see the output in emulator

Comment: I already have emulator installed. In my case "ionic  run android" is not building and launching the app. It just starts the phone in emulator.

Comment: may be you need to add path to the path variables